# How to enable seccomp profile on a predefined Helm chart in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, security, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, seccomp

I want to enable `seccomp` profile like `RuntimeDefault` in my AWS EKS Kubernetes cluster on a predefined Helm chart which doesn't have any specific parameter in the `values.yml` file to be updated. I don't want to download the chart and all the files locally to make changes in the `deployment.yml`.

What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

Kubernetes does not (currently) enable `seccomp` by default.

Following are the 3 possible ways to do so defined:

1. If seccomp profile is already defined with a type (e.g., `RuntimeDefault`) in the default `values.yml` file of the newer version of a predefined Helm chart then simply upgrading its helm chart to that version will enable it.
2. If option 1 is not possible, you can enable it on a predefined Helm chart by setting the seccomp profile type in the security context of a pod to `RuntimeDefault` as follows in the `values.yml` file depending upon the key used in the `deployment.yml` file. For example, let’s say that `securityContext` is the key used to define the `securityContext` in the `deployment.yml` file. So, the following will be added in the `values.yml` file:

```
securityContext:
  seccompProfile:
    type: RuntimeDefault
```

3. If option 1 and 2 are not possible, you can download its complete helm chart locally and use it after updating the pod’s specification in its `deployment.yml` file as follows:

```
spec:
  securityContext:
    seccompProfile:
      type: RuntimeDefault
```

*Note: It is not possible to apply a seccomp profile to a container running with `privileged: true` set in the container's `securityContext`. Privileged containers always run as `Unconfined`.*

#### More Details:

Seccomp stands for “Secure Computing Mode”. It’s a security feature of the Linux kernel. In simple words, seccomp restricts the system calls that a process can make. In case of Kubernetes, it is a process running in a container in a pod.

Would seccomp improve our security posture? Yes, as seccomp protects the kernel from unwanted system calls made by processes, which in turn protects the host and helps maintain the isolation expected in a containerised environment.

Seccomp operation is controlled through rules specifying actions to take based on the requested syscall. Rules are defined in a file and referred to as a seccomp profile.

Example profiles can be found here: [Restrict a Container's Syscalls with seccomp](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/security/seccomp/#download-profiles)

In a seccomp profile, you basically define `defaultAction` to be taken, `architectures` covered, `syscalls` to list specific calls to be allowed or not.

- `defaultAction`: specifies what happens when the container uses a syscall that you haven't explicitly specified an action for. E.g., `defaultAction: SCMP_ACT_ERRNO` filters out the syscall.
- `architectures`: specifies the architectures we are allowed to receive syscalls from.
- `syscalls`: is a list of syscalls and the action we take when we encounter them. `action: SCMP_ACT_ALLOW` means we allow the system call to get past our seccomp filter.

A good starting point when introducing seccomp to your Kubernetes cluster is to enable the default profile (RuntimeDefault). While general in nature and very likely to be overly permissive for most of your workloads, some of the most security-sensitive syscalls are blocked. This default seccomp profile provides a sane default for running containers with seccomp and disables around 44 system calls out of 300+. Significant syscalls blocked by the default profile can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/seccomp/#significant-syscalls-blocked-by-the-default-profile).

Docker, CRI-O or Containerd, all of these come with a default seccomp profile available in your Kubernetes cluster.

Some workloads may require a lower amount of syscall restrictions than others. This means that they can fail during runtime even with the `RuntimeDefault` profile. To mitigate such a failure, you can:

- Run the workload explicitly as `Unconfined`.
- Disable the `SeccompDefault` feature for the nodes. Also making sure that workloads get scheduled on nodes where the feature is disabled.
- Create a custom seccomp profile for the workload.

**Important Note: Cloud managed Kubernetes clusters like Amazon EKS, GKE, etc, are managed Kubernetes clusters, so, we cannot play with the kubelet which means we cannot enable it on node level for all the pods in one go.**